# Autocomplete options truncated in jquery dialog box

Tags: jquery, css, autocomplete, jquery-ui-dialog

I have an autocomplete input inside a jquery dialog box.
Autocomplete options are truncated to the size of the dialog box and I cannot have them displayed fully (without width and height limits).

```
<div id='test_dialog' title='test'>
   <form method='post'>
      <input id='autocomplete_input'>
   </form>
</div>
```

Here is a **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/patrick29/pwdff7yj/2/)** that reproduces my problem

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it helps you.

Comment: It seems better with jquery ui 1.10.2 ccs  theme than with jquery ui 1.11.2 css theme, but I would like this to work with recent versions...

Comment: It works fine with jquery ui 1.12.0-rc.1 css version, as shown in updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/patrick29/nb58j418/1/

Comment: Jad I accept your answer as it helped me solve my problem : i will upgrade jquery ui css version. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help you and Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be working fine, please make sure you are putting the right declarations in your html file:

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Output:

[image]


**### Check it out.**

Comment: Hi Jad! You are using jquery ui 1.10.2 instead of jquery 1.11.2 as I do. It seems in deed behaviour with jquery 1.10.2 is what I want. But I would like  this to work with jquery 1.11.2 or more recent versions. I am going to test with other versions to check behaviour. Moreover you added style="width:400px;" in html to have options one 1 line.